# How can I use the Optima font delivered with my Mac in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: fontspec, luatex

I am trying the following on my Mac:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\setsansfont{Optima}

\textsf{Test}
\end{document}
```

But I get the following:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Optima" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

I was under the impression this would work. What have I missed?

Comment: It seems that `.ttc` fonts are not found by the `mkluatexfontdb` script. The font is usable with `xetex`.

Comment: Future versions of luaotfload (> version 1.25) will work out of the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a file called `otfl-blacklist.cnf` in the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload`.

One line of it is

```
/Library/Fonts/Optima.ttc
```

`mkluatexfontdb` block most `TTC` fonts by default because they broken in previous version of LuaTeX. But with MacTeX 2011, they are usable.

There are several solutions to this

1. Try to edit the file mentioned above, so it will not block optima. (But this is not recommended, what if someday `luaotfload` was updated? Edit it again?)
2. Copy the optima fonts to a new directory such that muluatexfontdb will be able to find it, for example, `~/Library/Fonts` or one of fonts directory in `texmf` tree.

As long as you get the idea why fontspec cannot find it, as I explained above, you will certainly work around it. Good luck.

Comment: So are you saying that this is a problem that luaotfload has fixed, but the blacklist remains, and should be removed? Or is it just that some .ttc fonts work and some don't?

Comment: @AlanMunn I believe that it was actually a problem of `luatex` instead of `luaotfload`. At least all `TTC` fonts distributed with Mac OS X Lion, including /System/Library/Fonts and /Library/Fonts works for me with MacTeX 2011, namely LuaTeX 0.7 beta. Though the LastResort.ttf still takes forever to load. However I don't think `luaotfload` should change the blacklist as there may still be people using MacTeX 2010 for various reasons.

Comment: I can confirm that this works also with MacTeX 2011 on OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) as well.  So commenting out individual fonts as needed will indeed solve the problem.  I tried to do this with a local copy of the blacklist, but it didn't work. Any ideas on why?

Comment: @AlanMunn the global black list is always read I guess.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yan Zhou is correct about the global black list. Every black list it can find is read.

Comment: Thanks to @AlanMunn for pointing this out. There is/was an open issue on luaotfload. It seems that future versions of luaotfload support a whitelist. https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaotfload/issues/37

Comment: @Patrick yeah, I suggested the whitelist feature a while ago. It seems been implemented by someone. Is that you?

Comment: @YanZhou yes, I felt like writing the small patch after Alan pointed me to this question in the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2055829#2055829