# Transparent background on page 1

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, transparency

I try to include a 'Watermark' in some documents. To achieve that I use `eso-pic` and `tikz`. The problem is, that I don't get transparancy in one-paged documents. As soon as the document has more than one page everything is fine.

My MWE demonstrates that. Uncomment `%\newpage` and the background is transparent (even on page 1).

What is wrong with my code? What do I have to change to achieve a transparent background even on one-page documents?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, opacity=0.08]%
  \node [rotate=60,scale=10,text opacity=0.2] at (current page.center) {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
   \null
   %\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no problems with your code even with 1 page document. I'm using MikTeX 2.9 with last pgf and eso-pic versions.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. But `\newpage` doesn't add a page, the resulting pdf still is a one page document. So if `\newpage` at the end helps, why don't you use it? Btw: perhaps your problem is related to this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32184/tikz-eso-pic-watermark-isnt-transparent-on-the-first-page.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You are right, but this should not be THE solution :( I will give TomBombadils solution a try.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `background` package (which is based on `TikZ`). Note that you have to compile twice to get it working correctly.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{water free water mark}
\SetBgScale{7}
\SetBgColor{black!40!white}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]