# No transparency in TikZ pictures including external PDF graphics in XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, transparency

I was trying to create a tikzpicture environment which includes external graphics (as a PDF). The external graphics should be translucent, so I used the *opacity* parameter. Using pdfLaTeX it works as expected, but under XeLaTeX (which I need for other reasons) there is no transparency.
After checking some more, it appears to work fine under XeLaTeX for JPGs and (more importantly) EPS. If no more elegant solution can be found, I can use EPS graphics instead of PDF. But maybe there is a magical definition I can put in the header to fix this?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% Regular figure
    {\node{\includegraphics{pdfgraphics.pdf}};}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}% Pale figure
    {\node[opacity=0.3] {\includegraphics{pdfgraphics.pdf}};}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

And here are the results when using both engines:
[image: results when using both engines:]

Comment: Could you upload the included pdf somewhere for analysis?

Comment: What version of XeTeX are you using with which distribution on which OS?

Comment: Could be a bug in the XeTeX driver of TikZ. It might be better to ask this on a TikZ forum instead.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32184/tikz-eso-pic-watermark-isnt-transparent-on-the-first-page

Comment: This is clearly a bug in TikZ. As such, it's not really something that can be 'answered' in the way that the site works. I'll therefore close it: not a criticism but a reflection of the fact that we can't do much about it!