# eso-pic transparency not working together with tikz in title page

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I'm trying to add a transparent background image, and for that I have tried many options. The one I'm trying now is using `eso-pic` together with `transparent` packages. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar, backgrounds, external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./figures/tikz/]

\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\tt FIRST PAGE}} \\[10pt]
\vspace{0.75\baselineskip}
 \Huge \tt SUBTITLE
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{flushleft}
\Large
AUTHOR\\
\vfill
THE PUBLISHER {\normalsize 2018}
\end{flushleft}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\transparent{0.1}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{./background.pdf}};

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

However, if I load the `tikz` package (which I need throughout the entire document), I can't set the opacity in the figure to 0.2 as in the example. I tried following [the suggestion here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32184/tikz-eso-pic-watermark-isnt-transparent-on-the-first-page) on loading `tikz` first and then `iso-pic` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm your observation, and suggest the following workaround:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar, backgrounds, external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./figures/tikz/]



\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\tt FIRST PAGE}} \\[10pt]
\vspace{0.75\baselineskip}
 \Huge \tt SUBTITLE
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{flushleft}
\Large
AUTHOR\\
\vfill
THE PUBLISHER {\normalsize 2018}
\end{flushleft}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.5]\node at
(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzexternalenable}

\endgroup

\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
\def\def{\empty}
\begin{document}
\section*{Hello}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to simply use the Ti*k*Z opacity instead.

Comment: I need to use `external` in `tikz`. But if I use the disable/enable externalize then it works! Please edit the answer so I mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, and sorry for commenting out `\tikzexternalize`. I could only make it work smoothly by wrapping the background picture into `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable`.